# Simple calculation php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

hye guy,
Actually i'm still new in programming.
just wanna asking what wrong with this code?
i'm trying to make calculation inside a form.
Really appreciate if your guys can help.
Thank you.

```
<?php
$script = "
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
function calculate() {

var value1 = $('value1').value;
var value2 = $('value2').value;
var value3 = $('value3').value;
var value4 = $('value4').value;
var value5 = $('value5').value;


var total = ( value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5);


// Check that the result is a finite number. If so, display the results.
if (!isNaN(monthly) &&
  (monthly != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) &&
  (monthly != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {


  total.value = round(value1 +value2 +value3 +value4 + value5);

} else {
  // Otherwise, the user's input was probably invalid, so don't
  // display anything.

  total.value = '';

}
} 

// rounds number to two decimal places.
function round(x) {
return Math.round(x*100)/100;
}
$('compute').addEvent('click', calculate );
$('value1').addEvent('change', calculate );
$('value2').addEvent('change', calculate );
$('value3').addEvent('change', calculate );
$('value4').addEvent('change', calculate );
$('value5').addEvent('change', calculate );


 });
";
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($script);
 ?>
<table>
<tr><td colspan="3"><b>Enter Amount Information:</b></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td>1)</td>
  <td>Amount of the 1 :</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value1" id="value1" size="12" ></td>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <td>2)</td>
  <td>Amount of the 2 :</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value2" id="value2" size="12" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>3)</td>
  <td>Amount of the 3 :</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value3" id="value3" size="12" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>4)</td>
  <td>Amount of the 4 :</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value4" id="value4" size="12" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5)</td>
  <td>Amount of the 5 :</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value5" id="value5" size="12" ></td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="3">
  <input type="button" value="Compute" id='compute' " >
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">
  <b>Payment Information:</b>
</td></tr>


<tr>
  <td>5)</td>
  <td>Your total will be:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="12" readonly='readonly'></td>
</tr>

</table>
?>
```

Regards,
ADik mat

Comment: Isn't most of that javascript?

Comment: i wanna to make a calculation inside a form..and it will show the answer for the amount we entered in a same page..the problem is the answer did not show up when we input the value..

Comment: When/where are you displaying the calculated total?

Comment: when press the compute button..at the line : <tr>
  <td>5)</td>
  <td>Your total will be:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="12" readonly='readonly'></td>
</tr>

Comment: remove ?> at the end of the code

Comment: change to this code <input type="button" value="Compute" id='compute' />

Comment: thanks..but it still not working..

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
 $('#value1').val()
```

instead of

```
 $('value1').value
```

if you are using jquery and selecting elements by id

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Fix a mistake

remove ?> at the end of the code

## 2. wrong tag closure

change to this code

```
<input type="button" value="Compute" id='compute' />
```

## 3. Instead of using Window.event('domready')

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() { } );
```

If you're already using jQuery.

## 4. It is always good to put a table in

> `<body></body>`

tag.

That means you should start with

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        //put some contents like table
    </body>
</html>
```

## 5. I think pretty much of your javascript code can be reduced by using below snippet.

```
$(':text').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).each(function() {
        sum += $(this).val();
    });
    $("#total").val(sum);
});
```